# Is this good practice store state in variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have just started to study ReactJS and have some questions. I was reading documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/), but I can't find the answer I am looking for. Here is an example:

```
var Awesome = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function() {
    return {
      txt : ["1","2","3","4","5"],
      isTrue : true
    }
  },

  handleClick:function() {
    this.setState({
      isTrue : !this.state.isTrue
    })
  },

  render:function() {
    var changeStyle = {
      display: this.state.isTrue ? "block" : "none"
    };

    var message = this.state.txt.map(function(oneMessage) {
      return  <SubChild change={changeStyle} txt={oneMessage}/>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} >Click Me</button>
        {message}
      </div>
      )
  }
})

var SubChild = React.createClass({
  render:function() {
    return (
      <div style={this.props.change}>
        <h3>{this.props.txt}</h3>
      </div>
      )
  }
})

React.render(<Awesome />, document.body)
```

Everything works fine, but I have some questions. As you can see *I store my state inside a variable. Is this the best practice?* How can I achieve the same result without variables inside render function or actually without states (I am trying to avoid state). *Is this possible*? 
Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9641/)

Comment: Actually, I don't even see the line where you store state inside variable :) If you mean the variables in the `render` method, it is completely acceptable practice, you're not storing state here, rather you are storing pieces of the components you gonna render. It certainly improves readability and maintainability of the code

Comment: @beshanoe yeap i am talking about variables inside render function. Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why State Variables?**

The idea of using state variables is to have changing / dynamic data, ie if anything about the component is changing, it should be defined as a state variable in the component so user interaction can result in change of this variable and a change in this variable causes the effected component to re-render.

**Use of Properties**

If some value is changed for each instance of the component and is uneffected by user interaction or component state change, it should be defined as a property so it can be assigned only once at instantiation.

In all cases, we cannot really avoid the use of variables inside the render

Comment: hmmm..  good point, now my understanding more clear about states and  props. Thanks and + 1 for you @arkoak